# How to get text in the middle

Tags: python, pyspark

First of all, thanks for the help, I´m stuck on this issue for one week. I am new to PySpark and Python itself. I googled and searched it a lot, but I didn't find anything that could help me.

I´m using PySpark to develop a datamart. There is dataframe column which contains the following:

```
> {"table_name":"GF-DB.HUB_CHARGES.CORRELATIONID","login":"Captain09"}
> {"table_name":"FTTB.FTTB_MONTHLY_NEW.LOGIN.START_SERVICE_DATE","login":"0013896761"}
```

There are about 200,000 such entries in the column.

**What am I trying to get?**

I'm trying to get text that starts after **{"table_name":"** and ends before **","login":"Captain09"}**, that is, in the end I get **GF-DB.HUB_CHARGES.CORRELATIONID**.

I've tried to use:

```
t1.select(split(split('ADD_PARAMS', '"table_name":')), '"login":').show(2)
```

But it doesn't work either.

Comment: That's not a string, that's a dictionary.  Can you not just do something like `t1["table_name"]`?

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for the answer! But I already tried this option and it didn't work. It turns out that I already have a collected dataframe and in it this column is located from which I want to get the text in the middle.

Comment: **IF** it really is a string, you could just do `json.loads(t1)['table_name']`.  The sample you've showed is does not clarify what you really have.  It is clear that's not a good way to store your data.  How did it get that way?

Comment: @TimRoberts I honestly don't know how it happened and why it is stored like that. All I know is just to assemble a dataframe from 4 different tables that are in the database. I managed to assemble the dataframe, but the task is still not solved due to the problem that I described.

Comment: Here's the problem.  I can't be sure what your dataframe really looks like.  We can't tell whether it is a string or a partially interpreted string.  Somehow, you need to show us some actual output, including the column type.